# Bucle para líneas de ping en C

Tags: bucles

Ya casi tengo una parte de un trabajo en C en el cual necesito leer varias líneas de un txt inicial, conteniendo IP's separadas por saltos de línea, para lanzar pings a cada una individualmente, almacenar los resultados en un segundo txt tipo "out.txt" y, a partir de éste, buscar la palabra clave "Media" que me confirme que el ping ha sido satisfactorio y printar por pantalla la IP en cuestión.

Estoy encallado finalmente en el bucle a través del cual recorro las distintas IP's. Si lanzo este código tal cual, la primera línea que me lee es la segunda (la que corresponde a la segunda IP), no encuentro la manera de rebobinar el puntero en medio de una concatenación. Por otra parte, ¿qué tipo de bucle me recomendáis que permita cerrar el archivo, analizar las estadísticas, y reabrir para continuar analizando el resto de líneas?

Aporto la parte del código problemática en cuestión:

```
    strcpy(str, " >> out.txt");
    strcat(str, " ping ");
    strcat(str, ch);
    system(str);
    fclose(fp);
    fp2 = fopen("out.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp2)) {
        if (strstr(line, term) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", "\n\n   IP responde positivamente: ");
            printf("%s", ch);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Para moverte por el fichero puedes utilizar lseek: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Conozco el comando (fseek en Windows, si no me equivoco), pero tampoco me funciona. Parece que el ping sólo lo lanza a partir de la segunda línea de mi txt inicial, aunque cierre el archivo con fclose y lo reabra con fopen, rebobine con rewind o fseek..., no lo entiendo.